# Python Interpret this json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonparser

Im using the following code:

```
import json
full_json = "{'Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila': ['/nike/casual/', '100', '/medias/']}"
jtopy=json.dumps(full_json) #json.dumps take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.
dict_json=json.loads(jtopy) 

print(dict_json['Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila'][0])
```

how can I get the value:
**/nike/casual/runners/'**

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: "_json.dumps take a dictionary as input [...]_" but `full_json` is a string, not a dictionary

Comment: And `full_json` is not even a valid json string... You try to use the json module on non json input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not valid, you'd need to swap the single and double quotes.
Also you want `json.loads` instead of `json.dumps`

```
>>> import json
>>> full_json = '{"Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila": ["/nike/casual/", "100", "/medias/"]}'
>>> loaded_json = json.loads(full_json)
>>> loaded_json
{'Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila': ['/nike/casual/', '100', '/medias/']}
>>> loaded_json['Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila'][0]
'/nike/casual/'
```

Comment: @PhpCoder223 https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: @alex When i run that I get the following error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace' –

Answer (score 0):

Json does not accept single quotes in its strings. To do your query you should:

1. Replace your json string to this `'{"Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila": ["/nike/casual/", "100", "/medias/"]}'`
2. Run a json.loads `dictjson = json.loads('{"Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila": ["/nike/casual/", "100", "/medias/"]}')`
3. Do your query `dictjson["Nike - Hombres Tenis Fila"][0]`

Comment: is there anyway to replace the singe quotes with double using python itself?

Comment: Yes- the replace method. `json_string.replace("'", '"')`. Be careful though, this will replace quotes in the key names and values which could lead to invalid json..

Comment: When i run that I get the following error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: You have to replace a **string** not an object of another type... ie do it **before** you do json.loads

Comment: Heads up that trying to "fix" incorrect JSON can be the wrong approach. JSON is usually created via standard libraries, so getting an "incorrect JSON" means the data isn't actually JSON at all – it just looks *similar*. Fixing a few common, known differences can open an application up to bugs from uncommon, unknown differences.